# How to put file links into MS OneNote with drag-n-drop?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

I was always using drag-n-drop to put links (paths) to the files in OneNote document.

Now I lost this ability: if dragged, files are copied onto page in entire volume.

Why the feature has dispappeared and how to restore it?

**PROOF**

This is a screenshot after dragging PDF file onto a page

[image]

As you see, there is no option to insert a link.

If I drag DJVU file, I has no prompt at all and have the file embedded into the page.

**UPDATE**

OneNote version is 14.0.7116.5000 (64 bit) from MS Office 2010.

Previously with the same version of OneNote I was able to obtain the following dialog

[image]

As you see, it had 3 options with one option "Insert a link to original file" which now gone.

Comment: Does the link insert correctly and work, if inserted via Insert->Link?  Also, are the two files (pdf vs DJVU) located in the same place (on-disk, network, internet)

Comment: What version of OneNote are you using?

Comment: @Madball73 yes inserting links this way works fine